# SQL Only show First value of (where value is in the column more than once)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using sql to try to only where value is in the column more than once.
For example, If my table was to look like this, The Age column is showing 3 instances of the age '2'.

```
Increment | Agenda
-------------------------------------
2         | Minutes Previous Meeting
2         | Minutes Previous Meeting
2         | Minutes Previous Meeting
11        | First Aid
6         | PAT Testing
```

In this case, I would only want to show the first '2', So it would look like this:

```
Increment | Agenda
-------------------------------------
2         | Minutes Previous Meeting
          | Minutes Previous Meeting
          | Minutes Previous Meeting
11        | First Aid
6         | PAT Testing
```

**Revision:**

Here is the code i am using:

```
SELECT  A.Increment, 
        A.Agenda, 
        MS.Summary, 
        MS.Attendies, 
        MS.Appologies, 
        MS.Department, 
        MS.Date, 
        MS.WhoFor, 
        Ms.WhenFor, 
        MS.Name + ': ' + MS.Date as CreatedBy

            FROM HSAgenda A 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
            Meeting_summary MS ON A.Increment = MS.Id

            WHERE (A.Increment IN (SELECT SplitValue FROM dbo.Split ((SELECT Agenda FROM Agenda
                                   WHERE AgendaID=@AgendaID  ), ',') AS Split_1)) 
                                   AND (A.Increment <> '1') 
                                   AND (MS.Department = @Department) AND (MS.AgendaId=@AgendaID)

            ORDER BY A.Id, A.Parent
```

Comment: show the code you use..

Comment: This looks like something that should be done in the presentation layer of your application.

Comment: Per your question, all the 3 answers below will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT Age,
           Cat,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Age ORDER BY Cat) as rn
    FROM YourTable
) 
SELECT CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Age
            ELSE NULL 
       END as Age,
       Cat
FROM CTE
```

Comment: All 3 answers are correct, this is the one that worked best for me.

Answer (score 1):

Odd request - but try using a Window Function.

```
SELECT (CASE
            WHEN RowNum <> 1 THEN NULL
               ELSE Age
               END
       ) Age
       ,Cat
FROM 
    (
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Age ORDER BY Cat) RowNum
           ,Age
           ,Cat
     FROM dbo.YourTable
    ) Inner
```

Comment: You have an extra coma on `BY Age,`

Comment: Fixed it - Thank you Juan

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    case 
      when row_number() over (partition by age order by cat) = 1 then age
      else null
    end age,
    cat
  from myTable;
```